# chromecast didStart session: GCKSession delegate method is being called twice.

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

I am using Chromecast latest SDK to cast channels and videos on Chromecast , problem I am facing is chromecast didStart Function is being called twice.
below method is being called twice, smilarly willStart is also called twice.

```
 func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didStart session: GCKSession)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found answer after debugging, 
it is being added 2 times, so make sure you are adding sessionManager listener only once

```
 self.sessionManager.add(self)
```

and dont forget to remove it in viewWillDisappear.
     self.sessionManager.remove(self)